# How to upgrade maven plugins build in liferay 6.2 which is acceptable in liferay 7

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

Liferay 7 has changed its package names for many classes like,
User Organization Address etc.

Currently, I use Liferay version 6.2 for developing portlets. I tried to migrate from 6.2 to 7. Unfortunately, I couldn't because old packages are not resolved in new Liferay 7 container, and it makes sense.

Then I google and I found a tool to upgrade my current codes called CODE UPGRADE TOOL. Finally, i've stuck here, can anyone help me get rid of it?
[Error while upgrading portlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iba8.png)

Comment: So you have used *some* API, want to upgrade, tried *something* and now want to hear that you should try *something else*? Try *something* else. Like giving *more detail* about what you're *actually* trying to do. Last time I looked, Liferay's core API didn't go away.

Comment: Hi, Olaf, the Liferay's package names has been changed in Liferay 7, which is throwing error while deploying in OSGi container. Obviously, OSGi container will throw error while resolving dependencies. For example, the User class(com.liferay.portal.model.User) has been changed to this(com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User), there is lot more API has been changed.

Comment: That's exactly what the upgrade tool (you mention it) solves. Did you run it?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot in question just click on the last line of my question.